# What syntax do I use for the User and Friend Permissions while making a Facebook app?

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps, pyfacebook, facebook-app-requests

I am making a facebook app where, in the User and Friends Permissions I have chosen 'friends_birthday' and under the Extended Permissions I have chosen 'offline_access'

For the 'offline_access' the code is

```
facebook=Facebook('<api-key>','<secret-key>')
facebook.request_extended_permission('offline_access')
```

So I have used 'request_extended_permission' for getting Extended Permissions.
What do I use for the User and Friend Permissions?

Comment: offline_access is deprecated, please read https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming 'pyfacebook' works in a similar way to the official SDKs, just add the rest of the permissions you need as a CSV list to the same call:

```
facebook=Facebook('<api-key>','<secret-key>')
facebook.request_extended_permission('friends_birthday, user_birthday')
```

etc

Comment: I cannot do that since 'offline_access' comes under Extended Permissions and 'friends_birthday' comes under User and Friend Permissions as per http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/

Comment: Are you confusing the categorisation of permissions on the [Permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) documentation with the methods in the SDK you're using? Have you checked the code for the SDK to see what it does with the supplied parameters? If it passes them in the `scope` parameter in the call t the Auth Dialog it should work - there's **no** difference between how the different permissions categories are requested, they're all passed to the Oauth Dialog in the same parameter

Comment: Yes, after reading your previous comment, I did try to pass the rest of the permissions also in the same call itself, but, it doesn't work. 
I am not able to understand where am I going wrong.

Comment: I've had a look and it seems like that SDK is way out of date, and doesn't work with the current auth flows - it's still using the `ext_perm` parameter which went away with the Oauth 2 migration in October 2011

Comment: I feel you are right because here --> http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/prompt-permission/ when I refer to the table, column name perms, I get to see offline_access and also email in the same space. So probably, permissions are to be passed in the same call, but, it isn't working for me right now.

Comment: Here is the partial code

from django.core.management import setup_environ
from fbday import settings

setup_environ(settings)

def app():
    from facebook import Facebook
    
    #Get api key and secret key 
    facebook=Facebook('xyz','abc')
    facebook.auth.createToken()
    facebook.login()
    print "After you log in, press enter"
    raw_input()
    facebook.request_extended_permission('offline_access', 'friends_birthday')
    raw_input()
    facebook.auth.getSession()
    info = facebook.users.getInfo([facebook.uid], ['name', 'birthday'])[0]
    print info

Comment: I am sorry, can't put up a screenshot in a comment. So copy-pasted the code.